# QuickSort wrong complexity in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, quicksort

I'm doing some analysis of sorting algorithms and I faced a problem with Quick Sort. Looking for some charts on the Internet, I saw that my chart is significantly different from others charts, and I want to know why.

**This is my code:**

```
static int Particao(int[] vet, int min, int max, int modo)
{
    int i = min;
    int j = max;            
    int pivot;

    if (modo == 0)
        pivot = vet[(min + max) / 2];
    else
        pivot = vet[min];            
    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (vet[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (vet[j] > pivot)
            j--;
        if (i <= j)
        {
            int aux = vet[i];
            vet[i] = vet[j];
            vet[j] = aux;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    };

    return i;
}

static void QuickSort(int[] vet, int ini, int fim)
{
    int pivo = Particao(vet, ini, fim, 0);

    if (ini < pivo - 1)
        QuickSort(vet, ini, pivo - 1);
    if (pivo < fim)
        QuickSort(vet, pivo, fim);            

}
```

**My chart** (time is in ms and multiplied by 1000):

[image: Quick Sort]

Thanks =)

Comment: What kind of dataset are you testing your implementation with?

Comment: Numbers generated by C# native Random function

Comment: How did you time your implementation?

Comment: C# native stopwatch, I start the stopwatch before call the function then I call the function, when it return, I stop.

Comment: How stable is your runtime? When you measure the runtime with the same number of elements, does the time vary?

Comment: Why are you only measuring at 6 datapoints?

Comment: I'm testing at my notebook, Core I5 8265U, I using just 6 datasets because is the requirements of my assignment

Comment: Can you provide a chart showing the expected results overlapped with the actual results? It may not be so different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chart is different from the other charts due to differences in measurement.
The other charts had many more datapoints and many averaged measurements to keep errors out.

Your chart only has 6 datapoints with 1 measurement each and it is fairly hard to conclude anything from that.

Perhaps you could measure the amount of swaps or comparisons and extrapolate a graph from that?